# Unable to run a standardSQL query to bigquery in python

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am trying to query a table in Bigquery via a Python script. However I have written the query as a standard sql query. For this I need to start my query with '#standardsql'. However when I do this it then comments out the rest of my query. I have tried to write the query using multiple lines but it does not allow me to do this either. Has anybody dealt with a problem like this and found out a solution? Below is my first code where the query becomes commented out.

```
client = bigquery.Client('dataworks-356fa')

query = ("#standardsql SELECT count(distinct serial) FROM `dataworks-356fa.FirebaseArchive.test2`  Where (PeripheralType = 1 or PeripheralType = 2 or PeripheralType = 12) AND EXTRACT(WEEK FROM createdAt) = EXTRACT(WEEK FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) - 1 AND serial != 'null'")

dataset = client.dataset('FirebaseArchive')
table = dataset.table('test2')
tbl = dataset.table('Count_BB_Serial_weekly')
job = client.run_async_query(str(uuid.uuid4()), query)
job.destination = tbl
job.write_disposition= 'WRITE_TRUNCATE'
job.begin()
```

When I try to write the query like this python does not read anything past on the second line as the query.

```
query = ("#standardsql 
         SELECT count(distinct serial) FROM `dataworks-356fa.FirebaseArchive.test2`  Where (PeripheralType = 1 or PeripheralType = 2 or PeripheralType = 12) AND EXTRACT(WEEK FROM createdAt) = EXTRACT(WEEK FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) - 1 AND serial != 'null'")
```

The query Im running selects values that have been produced within the last week. If there is a variation of this that would not be required to use standardsql I would be willing to switch my other queries as well but I have not been able to figure out how to do that. I would prefer for this to be the last resort though. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to flag you'll be using Standard SQL inside the query itself, you can build it like:

```
query = """#standardSQL
           SELECT count(distinct serial) FROM `dataworks-356fa.FirebaseArchive.test2`  Where (PeripheralType = 1 or PeripheralType = 2 or PeripheralType = 12) AND EXTRACT(WEEK FROM createdAt) = EXTRACT(WEEK FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) - 1 AND serial != 'null' 
        """
```

Another option you can use as well is setting the property `use_legacy_sql` of the `job` created to `False`, something like:

```
job = client.run_async_query(job_name, query)
job.use_legacy_sql = False # -->this also makes the API use Standard SQL
job.begin()
```